# boto set_contents_from_filename memory leak

Tags: python, boto

I'm seeing a memory leak when using boto to upload files.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Memory usage seems to increase less consistently if I remove the sleep or if I don't alternate between two different buckets.

```
import time, resource, os

import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3()
for i in range(20):
  print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
  path = 'test.png'
  bucket = conn.lookup('jca-screenshots-' + ('thumbs' if i % 2 == 0 else 'normal'))
  k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
  k.key = os.path.basename(path)
  k.set_contents_from_filename(path)
  time.sleep(5)
```

Sample output:

```
12406784
13123584
13242368
13344768
13398016
13422592
13484032
13524992
13553664
13590528
13656064
13664256
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by switching libs: https://github.com/tax/python-requests-aws

```
import time, resource, os

import requests
from awsauth import S3Auth

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.boto")) as f:
  lines = f.read().splitlines()
ACCESS_KEY = lines[1].split(' = ')[1]
SECRET_KEY = lines[2].split(' = ')[1]

for i in range(20):
  print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
  url = 'http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/{}'.format(
    'jca-screenshots-' + ('thumbs' if i % 2 == 0 else 'normal'), 'test.png')
  with open('test.png', 'rb') as f:
    resp = requests.put(url, data=f, auth=S3Auth(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY))
  print 'resp:', resp
  time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: how is the memory usage on this one? I am experiencing a similar thing, but This won't work for me as I am using IAM roles, and have to retrieve credential from somewhere else.