# Boto S3 set_contents_from_filename gets stuck on large files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am having a problem that large file (over 1GB) uploads to s3 get stuck when using boto `set_contents_from_filename`.

I have tried using `set_contents_from_file` instead, and I am getting the same thing.

I am using the `cb` argument on both functions to call a callback function while uploading which will tell me how is the upload progressing. I see that a 1GB file gets stuck somewhere around 800MB.

EDIT: It seems that this function has a memory leak, as described here:
[boto set_contents_from_filename memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067814/boto-set-contents-from-filename-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use `boto`, which is slowly becoming obsolete.

In long term, changing to `boto3` is inevitable as older `boto` is not really maintained. See [`boto3` is not a replacement of `boto` (yet?)](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3306)

You may find example of uploading files here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636604/346478